# insert loop only inserts one row not all row

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';

    $msg= "Quntity is less than 10";


    $numResults = mysqli_query($conn, "select  COUNT(*) as `count` from item  where item_quantity <10");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($numResults);
    $count = $row['count'];
    if ($count>0) {



        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select item_name from item  where item_quantity <10");

        while ($notify = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {




            $td2 = $notify['item_name'];
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert  into notification (notification_name ,msg , status , notification_date)
VALUES('$td2','$msg','unread' , current_time )");

        }


    }
?>
```

The problem here is the code execute every time when I refresh the page and insert loop only inserts one row not all row.

Comment: In your loop you re-use the `$query` variable which is also the SELECT.  Your code could do with a few changes to use prepared statements, remove the unnecessary first `SELECT` and convert the `INSERT` into an `INSERT...SELECT...` (sorry, I'm just on my way out, but this comment may help).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for first fetching the data from the database just to write it back again. You can just issue an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` here.

```
INSERT INTO notification
            (notification_name,
             msg,
             status,
             notification_date)
            SELECT item_name,
                   'Quntity is less than 10',
                   'unread',
                   current_time
                   FROM item
                   WHERE item_quantity < 10;
```

---

To always have accurate figures you can create a view, that computes the messages if necessary.

```
CREATE VIEW notification
AS
SELECT item_name,
       'Quntity is less than 10',
       'unread',
       current_time
       FROM item
       WHERE item_quantity < 10;
```

Comment: That inserting work good, but when I refresh the page is inserting again I want  when I refresh the page just check if they are new item_quantity <10 and insert it .
do you have any idea for that